# xcworkspaceを開いてもPods以下のファイルしか表示されない

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

cocoapodsを使用し、AFNetworkingを導入したのですが、xcworkspaceを開いても、下記のような表示になり、元々あったファイルが編集出来ません。解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。
[image: Xcode]

Podfile

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AFTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AFTest
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

  target 'AFTestTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'AFTestUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: AFTestのプロジェクトを別のウインドウで開いていませんか？Xcodeでは同時に開けるプロジェクトは一つなので、すでにプロジェクトを開いているとそうなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
開いていたXcodeとコンソール等のソフトウェアを全て閉じて開き直したらプロジェクト内のファイルを表示させることが出来ました！